# MySQL update data by changing first character

Tags: mysql

I have mysql data table like this:

```
ID ---- Code
1  ---- A0001
2  ---- A0002
3  ---- A0003
4  ---- B0004
5  ---- B0005
```

I want to change (update) all data which first char is 'A' to 'B'. So the result would be like this:

```
ID ---- Code
1  ---- B0001
2  ---- B0002
3  ---- B0003
4  ---- B0004
5  ---- B0005
```

I already tried this query:

```
UPDATE `m_anggota` 
SET anggota_barcode = REPLACE(anggota_barcode, 'A', 'B') 
WHERE anggota_barcode LIKE 'A%'
```

But it's not working (0 rows affected). Anyone know why and how to fix this query?

Comment: Is this an error that you are looking for value starting by C ?

Comment: your query update all code which have c  in code . you want to replace all a occurrence

Comment: Your query is replacing `A` with `C` in strings that already begin with `C` (and probably according to your example don't contain `A` at all)

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson yes.. its a shame for me... I forgot to change that clause :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just have to change

```
WHERE anggota_barcode LIKE 'C%'
```

By

```
WHERE anggota_barcode LIKE 'A%'
```

because you are looking for occurrence that have an A in begining , not a C.

Answer (score 0):

Try This 
Its according to change your query

```
UPDATE `m_anggota` 
SET anggota_barcode = REPLACE(anggota_barcode,'A','B')
WHERE anggota_barcode LIKE 'A%';
```

but in your expected output column_name is different so query is

```
UPDATE `m_anggota` 
SET anggota_barcode = REPLACE(Code,'A','B')
WHERE Code LIKE 'A%';
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do dynamically like this

```
update m_anggota
set anggota_barcode = REPLACE(anggota_barcode,LEFT(anggota_barcode, 1),'B') 
WHERE anggota_barcode LIKE 'A%';
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11501505)

Comment: its working . i have tested it.  if you are getting mysql warning then follow these steps and disable mysql safe udpate >>> Go to Edit --> Preferences
Click "SQL Editor" tab and uncheck "Safe Updates" check box
Query --> Reconnect to Server // logout and then login
Now execute your sql query

Comment: I saw this in the review queue, so it was absent of context; however, typically answers need to have a bit more explanation than "here, try this."